# long TTFB on php7 apache

Tags: php, apache, performance

I had just installed PHP7 on apache 2.4, debian 8.
Chrome client, I had used `ctrl-f5` to prevent loading from cache.

I am running the next 2 files, times are avg:
1. hello.php (206ms TTFB)

```
<?php echo "hello world";
```

2. hello.html (5ms TTFB)

```
hello world
```

PHP: Opcode Caching Up and Running

As you can see there is huge difference between the two.
**What can I do to speed up PHP slow process?

it's seems like an Apache problem.**

Comment: Can You resolve this problem?

Comment: Sorry no, I had moved to Ubuntu :-(